# shell script display not functioning

Tags: shell

i got this code below which is to display the fields based on user input and the program will grab the other remaining field the correct display that i wish to see is

```
Found 2 records
The Hunger Games, Suzanne Collins, 1, 1, 1
The Hunger Games, Test, 1, 1, 1
```

but with the current code below the display is

```
Found 2
the hunger games
the hunger games, suzanne collins
test, 1
1, 1
1, 1
1
```

the input of the file is

```
The Hunger Games:Suzanne Collins:1:1:1
The Hunger Games:test:1:1:1
```

hope someone can assist me on this

```
echo "Enter Title: "
read title
echo "Enter Author: "
read author
result=$(grep -ise "$title\:$author" BookDB.txt)
record=$(grep -io "$title" BookDB.txt | uniq -c)
if [ "$result" != "" ] && [ "$author" == "" ]
then 
echo "found: " $record "records" | awk '{print $1  $2}'
echo "" 
title=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 1 -d ":")
author=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 2 -d ":")
price=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 3 -d ":")
qty_ava=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 4 -d ":")
qty_sold=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 5 -d ":")
echo ""
echo -e "$title", "$author", ""\$"$price", "$qty_ava", "$qty_sold"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well my method is not exactly the best but run double while loop for the record, without printing all the details first to count the record and another loop again to get the details. its not the best or efficient method

```
echo "Enter Title: "
read title_r
echo "Enter Author: "
read author_r
while read -r result
do
title=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 1 -d ":")
author=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 2 -d ":")
price=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 3 -d ":")
qty_ava=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 4 -d":")
qty_sold=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 5 -d ":")
if echo "$title" | grep -iq "$title_r" && echo "$author" | grep -iq "$author_r";
then
let record++

fi  
done < ./BookDB.txt

echo "Number of books found: " $record  
while read -r result
do
title=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 1 -d ":")
author=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 2 -d ":")
price=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 3 -d ":")
qty_ava=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 4 -d":")
qty_sold=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 5 -d ":")
if echo "$title" | grep -iq "$title_r" && echo "$author" | grep -iq "$author_r";
then
let record++
echo -e "$title,$author,"\$"$price,$qty_ava,$qty_sold"      
fi  
done < ./BookDB.txt
#echo "Number of books found: " $record 
echo ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cut, Just try using sed like:

```
sed 's/:/, /g' file.txt
```

it will search for ":" and replace every occurrence of it with ", "

Comment: using this will change the ":" inside the file i wish for it to be the same

Comment: @Ken yesi t will seach for colon and replace every instance by  comma followed by space.